# What causes weight loss and fatigue in Addison's disease?

Tags: pathology, endocrinology

Why would a lack of cortisol cause fatigue? In terms of normal functioning of the gland.

Comment: Cortisol is required for gluconeogenesis. So if you have low cortisol, then you will have low blood sugar, which causes fatigue. https://www.thebabbleout.com/health/cortisol/ According to wiki low cortisol causes increases lipolysis, but that part is not so clear. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortisol